# Cumulocity microservice storing data locally - size cap?

Tags: cumulocity

I'm storing some logs locally(in the deployed docker container) for my c8y microservice and exposing them via REST. What's a reasonable maximum size of the log data?

Answer (score 1):

Do not store any data in the container's file system This is not a supported use case and should not be done at all. All data that you want to store persistently must be stored in Cumulocity.

There is also a standard way of providing logs, that is supported by standard UI and can be viewed there, see https://cumulocity.com/guides/microservice-sdk/concept#requirements.

Comment: My experience with logs in the standard UI has been that they are buggy. This seems to be fixed now, but the log chunks the UI displays at a time are too small. If I'm interested in a log event that happened a few hours ago, I'd have to click hundreds of times to reach that log page. Is there some enhanced log viewer available, perhaps as an app, where I can specify the time range I'm interested in?

Comment: Yes there were issues with this feature in the past, they should all be fixed by now. If you still have concrete issues, please report them to support@cumulocity.com.
I agree that scrolling around in 10 minute segments is not user friendly in many use cases, but at the moment there is no other log viewing functionality.